# Using CSS to change the content of checkbox element

Tags: html, css

```css
input:checked ~ #value:after {
  content: attr("data-value");
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label for="checkbox1">checkbox1</label>
  <input type="radio" name="check" id="checkbox1" data-value="A">
  <label for="checkbox2">checkbox2</label>
  <input type="radio" name="check" id="checkbox2" data-value="B">
</div>
<h1 id="value">
  Letters:
</h1>
```

Is it possible to make **checked radio** to add its **data-value** next to **#value** using CSS only? Make it continue as

**Letters: A**
or **Letters: B**

Comment: You'll need js for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is a job for **Javascript**, but I can get you part of the way using **Pure CSS** using variables.. but this is obviously no better than having hidden `divs`.

```css
:root {
  --active-contentA: 'A';
  --active-contentB: 'B';
}

input[data-value='A']:checked   ~ #value::after {
 color: red;
 content: var(--active-contentA);
}

input[data-value='B']:checked   ~ #value::after {
 color: red;
 content: var(--active-contentB);
}
```

```html
  <label for="checkbox1">checkbox1</label>
  <input type="radio" name="check" id="checkbox1" data-value="A">
  <label for="checkbox2">checkbox2</label>
  <input type="radio" name="check" id="checkbox2" data-value="B">

<h1 id="value">
  Letters:
</h1>
```

See [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ldjv6ga4/)

This is the **Javascript** solution:

```js
document.addEventListener('input', function (evt) {
  var data = evt.target.getAttribute('data-value');
   var value =  document.getElementById('value');
   value.innerHTML = "Letters: " + data;
});
```

```html
  <label for="checkbox1">checkbox1</label>
  <input type="radio" name="check" id="checkbox1" data-value="A">
  <label for="checkbox2">checkbox2</label>
  <input type="radio" name="check" id="checkbox2" data-value="B">

<h1 id="value">
  Letters:
</h1>
```

See [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ldjv6ga4/1/)

**Goodluck!**